# Rails saving half of a post entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

Afternoon all,

I have a post model, which has a song name, song string fields and a user_id field. A user can create a new song with up to 10,000 characters. Now when saving a short song it displays it all just fine in its entirety, however when a user enters a long song say over 400 chars, it seems to cut most of it off displaying only about 200 chars, the same happens when editing, add the remains of the song and it still cuts it off. Database is Mysql and checking in the console, it doesn't seem to save the full entry either. The songs are written in keyboard format, e.g  E T W R[TREW] | WEER. Ive had a google and haven't found anything along these lines.

my code is as follows;

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :song, :song_name, :user_id, :rating
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ratings, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user

  before_save :rating

  validates_presence_of :user_id
  validates :song_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 70 }
  validates :song, presence: true, length: { maximum: 10000 }

  default_scope order: "posts.created_at DESC"
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
    @ratings = @post.ratings
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end


  def new
    @post = Post.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, success: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new", error: "please sign in to post" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, success: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit", error: "please try again" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

and the show.html.erb

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
    <h1><%= @post.song_name %></h1>
     <p>Transcript by: <%= @post.user.name %><br/>
     Rating: <%= @post.rating %>/10</p>
    <br/>
     <p><%= raw @post.song %></p>
    <br/>
     <span class="timestamp">
       updated <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.updated_at) %> ago.
    </span>
       <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %>
    <br/>
       <% if !signed_in %>
         please login to rate songs
       <% else %>
         <%= render partial: "ratings/form", locals: { post_id: @post.id }%>
      <% end %>
   </div>

<%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: { post_id: @post.id } %>
<%= render partial: "comments/show", locals: { comments: @comments, post_id: @post.id } %>
```

if anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated, and if you need more code just ask. cheers Andy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that the database field is defined as a varchar which limits the string to 255 characters. But I'm sure you can quickly check that.

Answer (score 1):

As Dane has already pointed out, you are probably trying to store these long strings in a database field with limited capacity (e.g. *varchar*, which has a fixed, definable length). Just use the field type *text* (which is unlimited in length) to save long strings...

To change your database use sql:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table CHANGE COLUMN your_column your_column TEXT;
```

or use a migration containing:

```
change_column :your_table, :your_column, :text
```

---

**Update:**
To avoid errors like this, you could also enable MySQL strict mode: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/02/07/beware-of-mysql-data-truncation/. Strict mode throws an error if you try to save a string that is too long in a field that is too short.

Comment: I just found out about strict mode and how it helps preventing these problems. Read the updated part in my answer...